# (Angular 4) Make constant HTTP requests to display data in real-time

Tags: multithreading, angular, web-worker

I have a REST API, which returns me the latest sensor data when I make a GET request. New data is being added every second. I would like to make a GET request every second, so I can feed the latest sensor data to a line chart to keep the user updated and give it a real-time feeling.

Since Angular 4 is unable to create background threads, I'm unsure how I can do this task. I found some information regarding Web-Workers, however I was unable to find a proper example. I'm also unsure how I would use a Web-Worker to keep returning new data, as it usually only returns one value (when the function is finished executing).

Is this even possible using Angular 4?

Comment: Please show the code that runs your GET and returns data to the app.

Comment: I think you should apply real-time technology whereby server will tell client when there are new data, not the other way around. I am using SignalR on my project with Angular 2 :)

Comment: @BeetleJuice    

` getSensorDataFor(projectID){ 
        this.http.get(this.apiAdress + 'SensorData/' + projectID).map(
            reponse => reponse.json()
            ).subscribe(
            data => this.currentSensorData = data
        );
    }`

Comment: I meant, add it to your question, so whoever wants to help you has better context.